# apache error is getting displayed instaed of custom 500 page

Tags: django

I have deployed my django app strictly as per the documentation.I am facing a problem whenever there is error in app it should throw a 500 custom page instead of default apache error log page.I have written this :-

urls.py

```
handler500 = 'citysom.event.views.server_error'
```

views.py

```
def server_error(request, template_name='500.html'):
    """
    500 error handler.

    Templates: `500.html`
    Context: sys.exc_info() results
     """
    t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.
    ltype,lvalue,ltraceback = sys.exc_info()
    sys.exc_clear() #for fun, and to point out I only -think- this hasn't happened at 
                    #this point in the process already
    return http.HttpResponseServerError(t.render(Context({'type':ltype,'value':lvalue,'traceback':ltraceback})))
```

Everything is working fine in my local machine but in the server 500 page is not coming.

Can anybody help me in this ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you solve your issue? I'm intrested in your solution as I am in the same situation,thanks